# How should I use Variables and jQuery Dom navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I was just wondering which is the correct or most efficient way of navigating through the Dom using variables.

For example, can I concatenate selectors

```
var $container = '.my-container';
$($container).addClass('hidden');
$($container + ' .button').on('click', function(){
    //something here
});
```

or should I use the jQuery traversal functions

```
var $container = $('.my-container');
$container.addClass('hidden');
$container.children('.button').on('click', function(){
    //something here
});
```

Is there a different approach, is one best, or can you use them at different times?

Comment: The second is obviously cleaner. I would stick to it. But note that they are not equivalent. The second should be `.find('.button')` if you want it to yield the same result as the first one. Or if you want direct children then the first one should be `$container + ' > .button'`.

Comment: The `$` prefix is used to denote that a variable contains a jQuery object - so in that respect your second example is more standard, besides being much easier to read and better practice due to the cached selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $ is usually used only when working with an actual jquery object. You generally shouldn't prefix anything with that unless it's really something from jquery.

Beyond that little bit though, performance-wise, your second bit of code is going to be faster. I made an example jsperf here: http://jsperf.com/test-jquery-select

The reason the second bit of code is faster is because (if I remember correctly) jquery caches the selection, and then any actions performed on that selection are scoped. When you use `.find` (which is really what you meant in your code, not `.children`), instead of trying to find elements through the entire document, it only tries to find them within the scope of whatever `my-container` is.

The time when you **wouldn't** want to use the second pattern is when you expect the dom to change frequently. Using a previous selection of items, while efficient, is potentially a problem if more buttons are added or removed. Granted, this isn't a problem if you're simply chaining up a few actions on an item, then discarding the selection anyway.

Besides all of that, who really wants to continuously type $(...). It's awkward.